# How to clean up a service when onDestroy() isn't called?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

When I push my app from Android Studio to my phone, a service it runs is killed and onDestroy is not run. I need to execute some code whenever that service is shut down. What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure the service is not bounded? I ran into the same issue and found that the service was still bound to an activity and there for onDestory was not called

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Android will also fail to execute onDestroy if it needs to kill the service to reclaim memory.

Comment: The work around is to store a boolean in sharedpreferences specifying when your service is started and when it is destroyed. If it is not set upon destroy, then when you start the service again you can check the variable and do the cleanup before the actualy starting the service . Thats the only method I can think of

Comment: Importantly, I need to do this work when the service is stopped, not when it is re-started.